# wireless communication between two devices in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have two different android applications running on two different android devices(let's say device1 and device2) and both devices are connected to the same WiFi network.

Now, I have to initiate a command from device1 which can be received by device2 and execute it and send the result back to device1.

device1 doen't have any info about device2 i.e. ip address, device id etc.. , so first it has to identify the device2 where 2nd android app is running and then establish the connection and start doing communication.

Please suggest me best possible way to achieve it.

Comment: how far is the both devices, if not more then 10 meters then you can use bluetooth for communication.

Comment: Distance is not an issue , it might be less than 10 meters but device could change , there might be a scenario where one device will be mobile(device1) and another one is TV(device2). I am not sure whether all android supported TV will have bluetooth in it or not.

Answer (score -1):

If the two devices are on the same sub-net it is actually easy. Unit 1 sends a broadcast that unit 2 responds to. Now they both have IP address's of each other.

Below expains local IP broadcast.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address